# Why the number of minority charge carriers not increase when we put a potential is reverse bias in a diode?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

When we put a diode in reverse bias, should not the electrons coming into the p side cross the barrier to the n side. We know that they are minority carriers here but why is their number less in spite of the battery providing electrons in ample to the negative side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to look at the complete system, or at least include the point where the metal wire coming from the negative battery side is attached to the $p$-side of the diode, in this case.

At that point the electrons (which are plenty in the metal wire) can flow into the diode's $p$ side but then they recombine with holes in there, so they only recuce the number of holes, giving that side a negative charge and a negative potential. It will quickly become too negative to accept more electrons from the battery.

Of course you can still ask: aren't those first electrons enough to annihilate all those holes so that we still end up with excess electrons in that region? That could happen in a very weakly doped $p$-material, but the designers of the diode will make the doping strong enough to prevent that at in the intended reverse voltage range of the diode. And even if the voltage becomes too hight then there are other things that will go wrong first (like avalanche in the diode-junction).